# Complexity of cardinality constrained maximum weight independent set problem

Tags: graphs, computational-complexity, set-covering

Given a graph with a set of nodes and edges, the goal of the maximum independent set problem is to find the maximum number of vertices where no two vertices are adjacent. This is well-known NP-hard problem. It's weighted version is obviously NP-hard too, where each vertex is associated with a weight and the goal is to find the independent set with the maximum weight.

I am wondering if there is any published result determining the computational complexity of the weighted version with a cardinality constraint. That is, finding the independent set of size at most $k$ with the maximum weight.

Comment: Complexity deals with computation time as a function of model size. Are you asking about complexity for a fixed $k$ (meaning increasingly large graphs but with the size limit fixed)?

Comment: Yes, I am referring to the case with a fixed k (as the unconstrained problem is already shown to be NP-hard). That, is, what is the optimal set of k items which maximizes the total weight?

Comment: In the general case, it remains NP-hard since $k$ may be set to $n$. If $k$ is fixed, then a brute-force enumeration is $O(n^k)$ thus polynomial.